# Compare field with value and return bool

Tags: sql, postgresql, npgsql

I'm trying move hash cheking from server app to PostgreSQL.
In other words I'm need calling a query to PGSQL, which compare string from query with string from field and return result of equal comparison as bool, but I don't know how do this without procedures on clear SQL.

upd: I have table **users** with field **password**(currently *text*, in the future - *bytea*). I want write sometihng like

```
select * from values ('WrittenPassword' = users.password) where username = 'someuser' ,
```

**which must return true or false as result of equal comparison**.

Comment: `SELECT fieldname = 'hashvalue' AS alias ...`

Comment: Vague question. Providing more details and posting what code you already have would help.

Comment: read again. 
Comparing string from field with another specified.

Comment: @ArmanStepanyan: don't be too picky too fast: the person who asks the question might understand the OQ better than you do.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use a [CASE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-conditional.html) statement to return certain values based on a condition:

```
SELECT 
    (CASE WHEN password = 'WrittenPassword' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS is_equal
FROM
    users
WHERE
    username = 'someuser'
```

Comment: What does the query return when the username does not exist, Okay? There is nothing to compare, Okay? please look up "three valued logic" Okay?

Comment: @wildplasser, if the username does not exist, it simply won't return any rows because the WHERE clause would filter it out. Otherwise, if the user does exist, then the password can only be equal to or not equal to the input string, and so you have to get either 0 or 1.

Comment: I know (and I think you know), but the result depends on how the caller handles the three valued logic (NULL := "no rows returned") The OP does not understand this, and is resorting to dude-speech. When three valued logic is present, we'll have to formulate even more precise.

Comment: If I got null, it simply doesn't change result flag in my code from false to true(I'm using bool.TryParse() instead of Parse()). Null can't be correct value of password, exactly.

Comment: You can always add logic for the NULL such as IF (col IS NULL) with an OR or AND as appropriate.  Obviously you could do likelwise for IF (col IS NOT NULL)